# React js create a download file from a json response from API

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, export-to-csv

I have a react js app that is receiving the following JSON object from the API.
How can I create a CSV file export from the JSON and create a download link for the user using react js?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "location": "232323",
            "name": "ZZZZZZZ",
            "phoneNumber": "2003223232"
        },
        {
            "location": "23334",
            "name": "XYZ",
            "phoneNumber": "1234323334"
        }
}
```

I am newbie to the react.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use react-json-to-csv library for this purpose. Add the library using:

> yarn add react-json-to-csv

Then use it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import CsvDownload from "react-json-to-csv";

import data from "./data.json"; // or you can use a file from api

const mockData = data;

export default function () {
  return (
    <div>
      <CsvDownload data={mockData.data}>Json to CSV</CsvDownload>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You data file i.e data.json will be:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "location": "232323",
      "name": "ZZZZZZZ",
      "phoneNumber": "2003223232"
    },
    {
      "location": "23334",
      "name": "XYZ",
      "phoneNumber": "1234323334"
    }
  ]
}
```

By pressing the button you can download the file.